# Twitter API v2 and v1.1

Tags: python, tweepy, twitterapi-python

so i want to use tweepy in order to post some tweets ( photos, and videos basically) and i am just using the free versin of the twitter developer account.
I know there are some limitaion, and by searching in the internet I got confused and I do not know if it has changed or what, but whenever I try to fetch some data or post it i get this error:

tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

My code is the one below :

```
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
   consumer_key= API_KEY,
    consumer_secret= API_KEY_SECRET,
    access_token= ACCESS_TOKEN,
    access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

media_file_path = "Downloaded_Files\ 2023_11_27\IMG_8018.PNG"

# Upload media
media = api.simple_upload(media_file_path)

#Post a tweet with the uploaded media
tweet_text = 'Check out this media!'
api.update_status(status=tweet_text, media_ids=[media.media_id])
```

I tried to use different authentification methods using tweepy.Client also but it did not work

Comment: You cannot read twitter data without a paid account. See: https://developer.twitter.com/en/products/twitter-api

Comment: Media is uploaded via v1.1 API as you are doing. You should get a media item id as a response and store it. Posting the actual tweet happens via API V2, so you need to use Tweepy.Client for that and then use the media item id. All this should be possible with the _Free_ access tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [free tier](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/products/free) only allows creating tweets. I guess you can't upload media with it.

Comment: The _Free_ tier does include media upload via v1.1 API according to [X's documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api)

Answer (score 0):

I remember the free tier hadn't support to upload media, just tweets, so you have to consider to pay for to do that.

Comment: The _Free_ tier does include media upload via v1.1 API according to [X's documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api)